# DataGrid scrolls a row if RowDetails is visible

Tags: wpf

I have a DataGrid displaying 'Parent' records.
First column has a button to show/hide RowDetails, made using this solution: [I need the Expand / Collapse for RowDetailsTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829137/i-need-the-expand-collapse-for-rowdetailstemplate).
RowDetailsTemplate is another DataGrid, displaying 'Child' records. One of 'child' columns' is a checkbox.
It all works fine if 'parent' has only a few 'children'.
But if there is a hundred 'children', I have a small problem:
expanding the RowDetails and clicking on any 'child' checkbox - would firstly scroll the 'parent' row to the visual top of the 'parent' grid.
And then I need to find that 'child' again, and click on its checkbox again, to have it checked. Is there a way to 'freeze' a parent, and to have checkbox ticked in just one click?

Comment: Tried with `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` ?

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just wanted a smooth scrolling in WPF listbox.

Here's [an answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033841/is-it-possible-to-implement-smooth-scroll-in-a-wpf-listview) to your problem.

With using:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```