# What is the best approach for nesting a sub datagrid in another datagrid in a WPF MVVM application?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm implementing a WPF MVVM application.

**I have the following data structures:**

```
public class ClientOrders
{
   public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;]
   public Description {get; set;]
   public int Quantity  {get; set;]
   public decimal OrderAmount {get; set;}
}

public class Clients
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string address {get; set}
   public string phone {get; set;}
   public List<ClientOrders> {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to use a single WPF DataGrid using the MVVM pattern to display the data.
The ClientOrders for each Client should be contained  within a subgrid.
That subgrid should be expandable/collapsible.

I would like to use the standard out-of-the-box WPF DataGrid (NO 3rd party controls).
What is the best way to design/implement this?
Can someone please point me to an example/tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need the Expand / Collapse for RowDetailsTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829137/i-need-the-expand-collapse-for-rowdetailstemplate)

Comment: ASh: Close, but not quite. How do I embed and wire up a subgrid, given my listed data structures?

Comment: keyword: DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate, make your own template. Expand/Collapse is already done

Answer (score 0):

What about two grids? Selected Client will specify which ClientOrders will be shown in the second grid?