# Why can't click button in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

this is my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_projectassitant" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding projectassitance}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="324" Margin="315,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="771" Background="White">

                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="60" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="press me" Width="55" FontSize="16" Click="Button_Click"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SELLS" Binding="{Binding Path='sells'}" FontWeight="Bold" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="16"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project" Binding="{Binding Path='project'}"  IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="16"/>                           
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Sometimes some controls(like button,checkbox) in the datagrid can't be focus on,but sometimes it can.

Is there any ideas for this situation?

Comment: I have used it according to your code and the program has been executed correctly. Can you enter the program code?

Comment: Please check that link [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046003/adding-a-button-to-a-wpf-datagrid). A similar problem and solution is available in that link.

Comment: My situation is: If there are five rows in Datagrid, when I move the mouse on the button in top three rows,it can't be focus on;but another two work correctly.